# Font Awesome icons in link field

Tags: theming, 8, navigation

I would like to have a font awesome icon in my link text.

```
<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Blogs
```

Since link fields are generated in LinkGenerator.php, they get escaped.

```
if (!SafeMarkup::isSafe($variables['text'])) {
  $variables['text'] = Html::escape($variables['text']);
}
```

There doesn't seem to be any way to bypass this by setting a HTML option to `TRUE`.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What's function you use in file twig template?

Answer (score 5):

You can define your own template.

For example as inline:

```
$link = array(
    '#type' => 'inline_template',
    '#template' => '<a href="{{ url }}"><i class="fa {{ fa_icon }}"></i>{{ title }}</a>',
    '#context' => array(
        'url' => $url,
        'title' => $title,
        'fa_icon => 'fa-pencil',
    ),
  );
```

If you are working on a theme or module you should define a template with its own name like `link_fa`, so that it can be overridden by other modules or themes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would there be any way for the user to define their own icon using this method?

Comment: You can do this with two methods, the simple one would be to add a field to your content type for the icon and then use the inline_template in preprocess. The second would be a module to define this special field with user input and field formatters, so you can easily extend any site with this feature.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to let the user chose an icon, maybe the [Link Icon](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkicon) module fits your needs.

> The Link icon module is a simple link field formatter to create icon classes based on a predefined set of link titles.
>
> Link icon is an icon-agnostic formatter, meaning it doesn't care for whatever icon you use. Any icon will simply work. It doesn't hard-code icon names, nor includes icons.
>
> Drupal supports unlimited values, the limitation is your available icon fonts.

Or if it doesn't fit, you can have a look at the [modules code](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/linkicon/tree/?h=8.x-1.x), to see how they have implemented the *field widget* and the *field formatter* as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Every font awesome icon also has a unicode associated with it, see the [cheatsheet](http://fontawesome.io/cheatsheet/). These unicodes look like `&#xf040;`. This means that you do not need to use the class, but can use this as a character instead.

There is however one big BUT. Just adding the unicode does not work, you also have to apply the font-awesome font to the HTML selector.

So in order to make `<i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Blogs` display a pencil, you could also use `<i>&#xf040;</i>Blogs` and add `font-family: FontAwesome` to the CSS of `<i>`:

```
i {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Also read [this Stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17254339/1293725).

UPDATE:

I misread the question, I thought the class got stripped from the tags, but it seems the entire tag is removed. In that case this is less helpful...

Answer (score 0):

In the view, you can rewrite the results.  For example, In view select the font awesome field and click on rewrite results and then tick the "Output this field as a custom link" checkbox.  There you can give the link